# create a macro for a logic applied across the selected variables to create new variables in SAS

Tags: sas

```
TABLE A       TABLE B                                                                                               
First         All variables from A                                                                                              
Second        Other_ID                                                                                              
ID_S          Other_DT                                                                                              
ID_S          Other_DL                                                                                              
DT_P          Other_DL                                                                                              
DT_S          Other_ Bill                                                                                               
DL_P          Other_Provision                                                                                               
DL_S          Other_Reference                                                                                               
Bill_P        Other_Diag1                                                                                               
Bill_S        Other_Diag2                                                                                               
Provision_P                                                                                                 
Provision_S                                                                                                 
Reference_P                                                                                                 
Reference_S                                                                                                 
Diag1_P                                                                                                 
Diag1_S                                                                                                 
Diag2_P                                                                                                 
Diag2_S
```

I need to create table b with all variables and new variables mentioned in table B based on the below logic using a macro in SAS

If First=1 and Second=1 then ID_P("Value is not missing") and ID_S("Value is missing") then 1 else 0 end as Other_ID
If First=1 and Second=1 then DT_P("Value is not missing") and DT_S ("Value is missing") then 1 else 0 end as Other_DT

Any inputs is highly appreciated

Comment: What is the list of words before your first sentence supposed to represent?  Your logic description seems to be a mix of SAS syntax and SQL syntax. It is probably better to just explain the logic in words if you don't have working code to share.

Comment: Can you pls put the sentence? thanks

Comment: SO the logic can be written in SAS, sorry for mixing up a lil sql as well.

Comment: if the first and second equals one then ID_P value is not missing and ID_S is missing then create a new var Other_ID as 1 and if it does meet the condition then Other_ID equal 0. Hope this is clear?

Answer (score 0):

So to test for missing use the MISSING() function.

Also SAS will evaluate Boolean expression to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE so you can just use an assignment statement to create an variable with 1/0 values.

So perhaps something like this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  Other_ID = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(id_p) and missing(id_s) );
  Other_DT = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(dt_p) and missing(dt_s) );
run;
```

If you have 25 of them then use ARRAYS to reduce the typing.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array P id_p dt_p;
  array S id_s dt_s;
  array other Other_id Other_dt ;
  do over P ;  
     Other = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(p) and missing(s) );
  end;
run;
```

You might use code generation (macro language or other methods) to generate the ARRAY statement from a list of values like ID DT,  But it is hardly worth it for generating three statements.  Just use copy and paste in your editor an clean up the three statements.

**If you just want to write code from data** the PUT statement is the most powerful way.  So if you have a dataset with the triplets of names, the two variables to test and the one to create.  Such as:

```
data varlist;
   input (in1 in2 out) (:$32.);
cards;
id_p id_s other_id
dt_p dt_s other_dt
;
```

If all you have is that OUT variable (and the names follow the implied pattern from your examples) you can build the IN1 and IN2 variables using simple SAS functions.

```
in1 = cats(scan(out,-1,'_'),'_p);
in2 = cats(scan(out,-1,'_'),'_s);
```

Then you can use that dataset to generate a series of assignments statements.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set varlist;
  put out '=((first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(' var1
          ') and missing(' var2 'id_s) );'
  ;
run;
```

Which you can then use in a data step to create the variables:

```
data want;
  set have;
%include code / source2;
run;
```

Comment: This solution if fine but I have more than 25 variables to be created based on the logic provided. A macro is easiest way to achieve this? pls advice

Comment: A macro will not make this any easier for 25 variables. But using arrays would.  If you do want to try code generation then make sure you know what code you want to generate first before starting to write the code that will generate what you actually want to run.

Comment: if array will I be able to choose the variables randomly?

Also can you show a sample will try to understand if my variables of choice can be applied for the logic

Comment: if/then/else as macro would work for this?

Comment: Update your question to actually explain what you are trying to do as I do not understand.

Comment: Other_ID = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(id_p) and missing(id_s) );
  Other_DT = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(dt_p) and missing(dt_s) );

I have to create the above indicators or vars for more than 10 vars and I wouldn't need to type in each line for a var, instead a macro or array must do the job.

Pls let me know if not clear! thank you so much

Comment: The above array may not work if I have a mix of numeric and character variables
Pls suggest an alternative?

Also the new var created must be like Other_ID

Comment: Yes.  If you have mix of types you cannot use a single array.  If you have the list of ID DT etc in a dataset then just use a data step to write out the 25 (or whatever number) of assignment statements to a file and then %INCLUDE the file where you want the assignment statements to execute.

Comment: Instead I want to write the logic ones and apply across selected variables that is where I'm not able to move forward.

Comment: Update the question to explain what you want to do.  Make it clearer what is the input. What code you want to generate based on that input.  Explain how the inputs will change that justifies using code to generate code instead of just generating the code once.

Comment: So , Table A has few columns using the Columns (First, Second, ID_P,ID_S, DT_P, ...25) need to insert the logic using

if var First=1  and Secondary=1 then I must look for variable ID_P and ID_S if the value is not missing for ID_P and missing for ID_S then create a new variable Other_ID with binary values 1 and 0. This logic can be used in a macro to get all the varaibles done in one step instead typing the condition for each variable.

Please let me know if this is clear?

Comment: Of course the dataset has the variables.  I cannot understand what you are asking for.  Do you need to figure out the names of the variables? Use PROC CONTENTS, it can write a dataset with the variable names.

Comment: First,

As you said the new variables Other_ created exist in table B with code you provided. That is not a problem. An array wouldn't work to create the new variables as they are mix of character and numeric data types.
Second, I would need a macro to build the logic that would create all _Other variables in one step.
example:

Other = ( (first=1) and (second=1) and not missing(p) and missing(s) );

I do not want to write this 25 times that is possible by using a macro or an array. But array is not possible because the character and numeric data type don't mix.